# htaccess redirect url with file extension and trailing slash to no slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Can someone help me figure out how to redirect a url like this.

```
http://www.example.com/file.html/
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/file.html
```

I tried this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/ $1\.html [L,R=301]
```

but it redirects to

```
http://www.example.com/usr/www/users/user/folder/file.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a leading slash to your rule's target:

```
# slash here ------------V
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/ /$1\.html [L,R=301]
```